# Add library in my android project

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to use a library for my android project.
When I use an external library, everything works.
But when I add .jar to my folder "libs", there is this error :

```
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.allbrary/eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage.onCreate(CropImage.java:167)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
04-08 10:39:47.879: E/AndroidRuntime(13453):    ... 11 more
```

Code :

```
/**
 * The activity can crop specific region of interest from an image.
 */
public class CropImage extends MonitoredActivity {

    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024;

    private static final String TAG                    = "CropImage";
    public static final  String IMAGE_PATH             = "image-path";
    public static final  String SCALE                  = "scale";
    public static final  String ORIENTATION_IN_DEGREES = "orientation_in_degrees";
    public static final  String ASPECT_X               = "aspectX";
    public static final  String ASPECT_Y               = "aspectY";
    public static final  String OUTPUT_X               = "outputX";
    public static final  String OUTPUT_Y               = "outputY";
    public static final  String SCALE_UP_IF_NEEDED     = "scaleUpIfNeeded";
    public static final  String CIRCLE_CROP            = "circleCrop";
    public static final  String RETURN_DATA            = "return-data";
    public static final  String RETURN_DATA_AS_BITMAP  = "data";
    public static final  String ACTION_INLINE_DATA     = "inline-data";

    // These are various options can be specified in the intent.
    private       Bitmap.CompressFormat mOutputFormat    = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
    private       Uri                   mSaveUri         = null;
    private       boolean               mDoFaceDetection = true;
    private       boolean               mCircleCrop      = false;
    private final Handler               mHandler         = new Handler();

    private int             mAspectX;
    private int             mAspectY;
    private int             mOutputX;
    private int             mOutputY;
    private boolean         mScale;
    private CropImageView   mImageView;
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private Bitmap          mBitmap;
    private String          mImagePath;

    boolean       mWaitingToPick; // Whether we are wait the user to pick a face.
    boolean       mSaving;  // Whether the "save" button is already clicked.
    HighlightView mCrop;

    // These options specifiy the output image size and whether we should
    // scale the output to fit it (or just crop it).
    private boolean mScaleUp = true;

    private final BitmapManager.ThreadSet mDecodingThreads =
            new BitmapManager.ThreadSet();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        mContentResolver = getContentResolver();

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cropimage);

        mImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        showStorageToast(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            if (extras.getString(CIRCLE_CROP) != null) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }

                mCircleCrop = true;
                mAspectX = 1;
                mAspectY = 1;
            }

            mImagePath = extras.getString(IMAGE_PATH);

            mSaveUri = getImageUri(mImagePath);
            mBitmap = getBitmap(mImagePath);

            if (extras.containsKey(ASPECT_X) && extras.get(ASPECT_X) instanceof Integer) {

                mAspectX = extras.getInt(ASPECT_X);
            } else {

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("aspect_x must be integer");
            }
            if (extras.containsKey(ASPECT_Y) && extras.get(ASPECT_Y) instanceof Integer) {

                mAspectY = extras.getInt(ASPECT_Y);
            } else {

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("aspect_y must be integer");
            }
            mOutputX = extras.getInt(OUTPUT_X);
            mOutputY = extras.getInt(OUTPUT_Y);
            mScale = extras.getBoolean(SCALE, true);
            mScaleUp = extras.getBoolean(SCALE_UP_IF_NEEDED, true);
        }


        if (mBitmap == null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "finish!!!");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Make UI fullscreen.
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        findViewById(R.id.discard).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try {
                            onSaveClicked();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
        findViewById(R.id.rotateLeft).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mBitmap = Util.rotateImage(mBitmap, -90);
                        RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap(mBitmap);
                        mImageView.setImageRotateBitmapResetBase(rotateBitmap, true);
                        mRunFaceDetection.run();
                    }
                });

        findViewById(R.id.rotateRight).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mBitmap = Util.rotateImage(mBitmap, 90);
                        RotateBitmap rotateBitmap = new RotateBitmap(mBitmap);
                        mImageView.setImageRotateBitmapResetBase(rotateBitmap, true);
                        mRunFaceDetection.run();
                    }
                });
        startFaceDetection();
    }

    private Uri getImageUri(String path) {

        return Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();

            int scale = 1;
            if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
            in.close();

            return b;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "file " + path + " not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "file " + path + " not found");
        }
        return null;
    }


    private void startFaceDetection() {

        if (isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        mImageView.setImageBitmapResetBase(mBitmap, true);

        Util.startBackgroundJob(this, null,
                "Please wait\u2026",
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        final Bitmap b = mBitmap;
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                if (b != mBitmap && b != null) {
                                    mImageView.setImageBitmapResetBase(b, true);
                                    mBitmap.recycle();
                                    mBitmap = b;
                                }
                                if (mImageView.getScale() == 1F) {
                                    mImageView.center(true, true);
                                }
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            latch.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        mRunFaceDetection.run();
                    }
                }, mHandler);
    }


    private void onSaveClicked() throws Exception {
        // TODO this code needs to change to use the decode/crop/encode single
        // step api so that we don't require that the whole (possibly large)
        // bitmap doesn't have to be read into memory
        if (mSaving) return;

        if (mCrop == null) {

            return;
        }

        mSaving = true;

        Rect r = mCrop.getCropRect();

        int width = r.width();
        int height = r.height();

        // If we are circle cropping, we want alpha channel, which is the
        // third param here.
        Bitmap croppedImage;
        try {

            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    mCircleCrop ? Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        if (croppedImage == null) {

            return;
        }

        {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedImage);
            Rect dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, r, dstRect, null);
        }

        if (mCircleCrop) {

            // OK, so what's all this about?
            // Bitmaps are inherently rectangular but we want to return
            // something that's basically a circle.  So we fill in the
            // area around the circle with alpha.  Note the all important
            // PortDuff.Mode.CLEAR.
            Canvas c = new Canvas(croppedImage);
            Path p = new Path();
            p.addCircle(width / 2F, height / 2F, width / 2F,
                    Path.Direction.CW);
            c.clipPath(p, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
            c.drawColor(0x00000000, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        }

        /* If the output is required to a specific size then scale or fill */
        if (mOutputX != 0 && mOutputY != 0) {

            if (mScale) {

                /* Scale the image to the required dimensions */
                Bitmap old = croppedImage;
                croppedImage = Util.transform(new Matrix(),
                        croppedImage, mOutputX, mOutputY, mScaleUp);
                if (old != croppedImage) {

                    old.recycle();
                }
            } else {

                /* Don't scale the image crop it to the size requested.
                 * Create an new image with the cropped image in the center and
                 * the extra space filled.
                 */

                // Don't scale the image but instead fill it so it's the
                // required dimension
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOutputX, mOutputY,
                        Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);

                Rect srcRect = mCrop.getCropRect();
                Rect dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, mOutputX, mOutputY);

                int dx = (srcRect.width() - dstRect.width()) / 2;
                int dy = (srcRect.height() - dstRect.height()) / 2;

                /* If the srcRect is too big, use the center part of it. */
                srcRect.inset(Math.max(0, dx), Math.max(0, dy));

                /* If the dstRect is too big, use the center part of it. */
                dstRect.inset(Math.max(0, -dx), Math.max(0, -dy));

                /* Draw the cropped bitmap in the center */
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);

                /* Set the cropped bitmap as the new bitmap */
                croppedImage.recycle();
                croppedImage = b;
            }
        }

        // Return the cropped image directly or save it to the specified URI.
        Bundle myExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (myExtras != null && (myExtras.getParcelable("data") != null
                || myExtras.getBoolean(RETURN_DATA))) {

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putParcelable(RETURN_DATA_AS_BITMAP, croppedImage);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,
                    (new Intent()).setAction(ACTION_INLINE_DATA).putExtras(extras));
            finish();
        } else {
            final Bitmap b = croppedImage;
            Util.startBackgroundJob(this, null, getString(R.string.saving_image),
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            saveOutput(b);
                        }
                    }, mHandler);
        }
    }

    private void saveOutput(Bitmap croppedImage) {

        if (mSaveUri != null) {
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = mContentResolver.openOutputStream(mSaveUri);
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    croppedImage.compress(mOutputFormat, 90, outputStream);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot open file: " + mSaveUri, ex);
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
                return;
            } finally {

                Util.closeSilently(outputStream);
            }

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mSaveUri.toString());
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            intent.putExtra(IMAGE_PATH, mImagePath);
            intent.putExtra(ORIENTATION_IN_DEGREES, Util.getOrientationInDegree(this));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        } else {

            Log.e(TAG, "not defined image url");
        }
        croppedImage.recycle();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        BitmapManager.instance().cancelThreadDecoding(mDecodingThreads);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (mBitmap != null) {

            mBitmap.recycle();
        }
    }


    Runnable mRunFaceDetection = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
        float mScale = 1F;
        Matrix mImageMatrix;
        FaceDetector.Face[] mFaces = new FaceDetector.Face[3];
        int mNumFaces;

        // For each face, we create a HightlightView for it.
        private void handleFace(FaceDetector.Face f) {

            PointF midPoint = new PointF();

            int r = ((int) (f.eyesDistance() * mScale)) * 2;
            f.getMidPoint(midPoint);
            midPoint.x *= mScale;
            midPoint.y *= mScale;

            int midX = (int) midPoint.x;
            int midY = (int) midPoint.y;

            HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);

            int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = mBitmap.getHeight();

            Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

            RectF faceRect = new RectF(midX, midY, midX, midY);
            faceRect.inset(-r, -r);
            if (faceRect.left < 0) {
                faceRect.inset(-faceRect.left, -faceRect.left);
            }

            if (faceRect.top < 0) {
                faceRect.inset(-faceRect.top, -faceRect.top);
            }

            if (faceRect.right > imageRect.right) {
                faceRect.inset(faceRect.right - imageRect.right,
                        faceRect.right - imageRect.right);
            }

            if (faceRect.bottom > imageRect.bottom) {
                faceRect.inset(faceRect.bottom - imageRect.bottom,
                        faceRect.bottom - imageRect.bottom);
            }

            hv.setup(mImageMatrix, imageRect, faceRect, mCircleCrop,
                    mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0);

            mImageView.add(hv);
        }

        // Create a default HightlightView if we found no face in the picture.
        private void makeDefault() {

            HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);

            int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = mBitmap.getHeight();

            Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

            // make the default size about 4/5 of the width or height
            int cropWidth = Math.min(width, height) * 4 / 5;
            int cropHeight = cropWidth;

            if (mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0) {

                if (mAspectX > mAspectY) {

                    cropHeight = cropWidth * mAspectY / mAspectX;
                } else {

                    cropWidth = cropHeight * mAspectX / mAspectY;
                }
            }

            int x = (width - cropWidth) / 2;
            int y = (height - cropHeight) / 2;

            RectF cropRect = new RectF(x, y, x + cropWidth, y + cropHeight);
            hv.setup(mImageMatrix, imageRect, cropRect, mCircleCrop,
                    mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0);

            mImageView.mHighlightViews.clear(); // Thong added for rotate

            mImageView.add(hv);
        }

        // Scale the image down for faster face detection.
        private Bitmap prepareBitmap() {

            if (mBitmap == null) {

                return null;
            }

            // 256 pixels wide is enough.
            if (mBitmap.getWidth() > 256) {

                mScale = 256.0F / mBitmap.getWidth();
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        public void run() {

            mImageMatrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
            Bitmap faceBitmap = prepareBitmap();

            mScale = 1.0F / mScale;
            if (faceBitmap != null && mDoFaceDetection) {
                FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(faceBitmap.getWidth(),
                        faceBitmap.getHeight(), mFaces.length);
                mNumFaces = detector.findFaces(faceBitmap, mFaces);
            }

            if (faceBitmap != null && faceBitmap != mBitmap) {
                faceBitmap.recycle();
            }

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    mWaitingToPick = mNumFaces > 1;
                    if (mNumFaces > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < mNumFaces; i++) {
                            handleFace(mFaces[i]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        makeDefault();
                    }
                    mImageView.invalidate();
                    if (mImageView.mHighlightViews.size() == 1) {
                        mCrop = mImageView.mHighlightViews.get(0);
                        mCrop.setFocus(true);
                    }

                    if (mNumFaces > 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(CropImage.this,
                                "Multi face crop help",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    public static final int NO_STORAGE_ERROR  = -1;
    public static final int CANNOT_STAT_ERROR = -2;

    public static void showStorageToast(Activity activity) {

        showStorageToast(activity, calculatePicturesRemaining(activity));
    }

    public static void showStorageToast(Activity activity, int remaining) {

        String noStorageText = null;

        if (remaining == NO_STORAGE_ERROR) {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING)) {

                noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.preparing_card);
            } else {

                noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.no_storage_card);
            }
        } else if (remaining < 1) {

            noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.not_enough_space);
        }

        if (noStorageText != null) {

            Toast.makeText(activity, noStorageText, 5000).show();
        }
    }

    public static int calculatePicturesRemaining(Activity activity) {

        try {
            /*if (!ImageManager.hasStorage()) {
                return NO_STORAGE_ERROR;
            } else {*/
            String storageDirectory = "";
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            }
            else {
                storageDirectory = activity.getFilesDir().toString();
            }
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(storageDirectory);
            float remaining = ((float) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                    * (float) stat.getBlockSize()) / 400000F;
            return (int) remaining;
            //}
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // if we can't stat the filesystem then we don't know how many
            // pictures are remaining.  it might be zero but just leave it
            // blank since we really don't know.
            return CANNOT_STAT_ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

Why ?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: faced with the same issue and still looking for solution

Comment: There is always a nullpointerexception...

Comment: if you find the solution, let me know please

Answer (score 1):

Add jar file using following procedure :-

Right click on the project--->Build Path--->Configure Build Path...--->In left side you have to choose Java Build Path--->Libraries--->Add External JARs--->ok--->ok

Hope this will resolve the issue

Comment: There is an error in your code which is causing null pointer exception  . Not due to jar file

Comment: Just try to clean built your project and build path.Hope this might help.

Comment: This problem also happened if you have multiple version of libraries included in your build path physically. Removing the unused libraries from libs path, clean and save the project, restarts Eclipse and recompile it again do working for me.

Comment: Do you know why there is error : NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: May be your code is not able to find class definition. Try to solve this your self.

Comment: in fact, my R.java file is not generated. Do you know why ?

Comment: Some times if your project contains any error then R.java will not be created

Comment: R.java of my project is created but not R.java of my library

Answer (score 0):

This is a build path issue.

Make sure your bin folder is not included in your build path.

Right click on your project > go to properties > Build Path.

Make sure that Honeycomb library is in your libs/ folder and not in your source folder.

Include the libraries in libs/ individually in the build path.

BTW, you may want to bring in the android-support-v4 library to get Ice Cream Sandwich support instead of the Honeycomb support library

Answer (score -1):

You cant simply add the jar files in your app.. Go to buildpath and then add external jars into your app then it will work